# Jquery - Horizontally Center element to parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, centering

I am trying to horizontally center a dynamic element to dom level parents that have different widths.

I have most everything down but I am just calculating it wrong.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

NOTE: The width of the item I need centered is 20px

**Script**

```
$(function() {

$(".nav-menu").children("li").each(function() {

    $(this).on( "mouseenter", function(){   
    listWidth = $(this).find("a").width() /2 ; //<-- calculating width of each li
        $(this).find(".sub").prepend('<li id="nav-hover-state"></li>');
        $(this).find("#nav-hover-state").attr('style', 'margin-left:'+listWidth +'px');
    });

    $(this).on( "mouseleave", function(){   
        if($('.nav-container ul.nav-menu li .sub').attr('style','display:none')) {
        $(this).find("#nav-hover-state").remove();

    }
    });
});
```

Comment: 'margin: 0 auto;' should center it inside its parent side to side.

Comment: Unfortunately due to where I have to append the element I am forced to use absolute positioning.  I'm sorry It is not directly under the element that I am centering under. I need to change the wording.

Comment: Ok, does adding 10 to the listwidth work? you get half the parent, but do not account for the inner item

Comment: You were on the right track! I tried adding 10 but that just pushed it farther right. I had to subtract 10 to pull it half way back to the left. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subtract half the size of your inner element

```
listWidth = ($(this).find("a").width() /2) - 10 ; //<-- calculating width of each li
```

Comment: listWidth = ($(this).find("a").width() /2) -10; actually did it for me since I was pushing from the left I had to subtract 10
Thank you

Comment: you are right I meant subtract. changed my answer to match